# ActionBarSherlock's menuInflater is doing odd things

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying to convert a dynamically created menu into an xml one and get ActionBarSherlock to inflate it correctly. I does put some stuff on the actionbar, so I am doing something right. The results however are more than weird.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

#### Here is my res/menu/editor.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="Save" android:visible="true"/>

    <menu android:id="@+id/menu_para" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H" android:visible="true">
        <item android:id="@+id/para_h1" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H1" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/para_h2" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H2" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/para_h3" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H3" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/para_h4" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H4" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/para_h5" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="H5" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/para_text" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="T" android:visible="true"/>
    </menu>
    <menu android:id="@+id/menu_bullets" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="*1" android:visible="true">
        <item android:id="@+id/bullets_dots" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="*" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/bullets_numbers" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="1" android:visible="true"/>
    </menu>
    <menu android:id="@+id/menu_em" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="i-B" android:visible="true">
        <item android:id="@+id/em_italic" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="i" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/em_bold" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="B" android:visible="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/em_both" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="iB" android:visible="true"/>
    </menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

#### Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        Log.i("MyApp", "About to run inflater");
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.editor, menu);
        Log.i("MyApp", "Inflate done");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        Log.i("MyApp", "About to run inflater");
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.editor, menu);
        Log.i("MyApp", "Inflate done");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

#### For those who think I didn't do my research first here are my imports

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
```

## Results

### As is

Four buttons visible on the action bar

- `SAVE` - which currently does nothing
- `SAVE` - which opens up a menu containing H1, H2, H3, ..., H6, T
- `*` - which does nothing
- `1` - which does nothing

### If I delete first <item>, the one with title "Save"

Two buttons

- `*` - which does nothing
- `1` - which does nothing

### Weirdness

- There is only one <item> with title "Save".
- Without the `SAVE` item the headers submenu completely disappears, and with it, its title is wrong.
- `*` and `1` should be in a submenu.